# jqgrid dynamic row that spans all columns?

Tags: jqgrid

Wanting to add a new row under the current row based on a data condition and make that row span all columns. So I'm thinking add it in a formatter but I'm not sure how to get the spanning.

Comment: Looks like this would have to be done on gridComplete rather than a formatter so that the grid is loaded and then adjust the row. Any easier way? I would rather not have to parse the grid data after the fact if possible.

Comment: `make that row span all columns` - I do not believe jqGrid supports this feature, at least not for rows that contain data.